# Bluetooth Button on Windows 11 Keeps Disappearing

Tags: windows, drivers, bluetooth, troubleshooting

Every now and then, my computer's bluetooth functionality turns off. Usually this fixes itself with a restart of the device, but the issue is persistent enough that it is troublesome.

When the issue arises, the action center does not display the bluetooth button which is usually present:

[image]

Now, I have tried various troubleshooters to no avail. Upon probing the device manager, I can see that (when the issue is present), the Bluetooth driver is present as a "hidden device", with its icons sort of greyed-out.

[image]

What can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your BlueTooth is integrated with the Wireless card, I suggest you fully reinstall the wireless / bluetooth card.

First download the driver for your wireless card.

Now go to Device Manager and remove (uninstall) the wireless card, install the driver and restart.

See if now the BlueTooth icon is more stable.

I have two machines with BlueTooth and the BT Icon shows on both machines.